# Duda optimizacion query sql server

Tags: sql

Buenas tengo la siguiente query en sql server:

```sql
SELECT 
  [Info1],
  [Info2],
  [Info3],
  [Info4],
  [Info5],
  [Info6],
  [Info7],
  [Info8], 
  CONVERT(DATE, [DateTime]) as [Date],
  DATEPART (hh,DateTime) as [Hour],
  [DateTime],
  Lead(DateTime,1) over (partition by Program,Phase order by DateTime) as EndDateTime,
  [Info9],
  [Info10],
  [Info11],
  [Info12],
  [Info13],
  [Info14],
  [Info15],
  [Info16],
  [Info17],
  [Info18],
  [Info19],
  [Info20],
  [Info21],
  [Info22],
  [Info23],
  [Info24],
  [Program],
  [Phase],
  [Status],
  RankingGroup = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Program],[Phase],DATEPART (hh,DateTime),
  CONVERT(DATE, [DateTime]) ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC ) 
FROM 
  dbo.Table
WHERE 
  DateTime >= '2019-05-02'
```

La cual realiza lo que quiero, pero es muy lenta. La query esta hecha sobre una tabla que arroja 1.500.000 filas de resultado. La query me tarda 1 min 40 seg. He visto que lo que me ralentiza la query es la obtencion del EndDateTime y el RankingGroup. Alguien me podria ayudar a hacer la consulta mas rapida.

Comment: Para poder ayudarte, deberiamos ver, el total de la tabla, el query explain, un explain de la tabla.. asi como esta, es imposible saber que te falta o no te falta como para ver como se puede mejorar. Solo podriamos suponer escenarios...

Comment: la tabla contiene todas las columnas anteriores menos Date, Hour, EndDateTime y RankingGroup que se calculan como se muestra en la query. El EndDateTime lo que hace es obtener la fecha del DateTime del registro siguiente que esta particionado por program y por la phase de ese program. y el RankingGroup hace un ranking descendiente colocando 1 al ultimo registro que haya habido de esa program por phase y por día (DateTime).

Comment: Coincido con gbianchi, la consulta es simple como para que tenga algún problema desde la construcción del SQL. Habría que analizar, al menos estructura de la tabla e índices, y mucho mejor si además agregaras el query plan. Algunos comentarios 1) El problema esta en la query? o el minuto cuarenta se lo lleva el traslado por la red de 1.5 millones de filas? Prueba reducir la consulta a un simple `COUNT()`? cuanto demora esto? 2) Prueba quitando las columnas con `over` ¿cuanto demora la consulta ahora? 3) `DateTime` tiene índice? de que tipo es?

Comment: Lo que compruebo es que si realizo esa misma query pero colsultando solo 4-5 columnas el tiempo se me reduce hasta 15 segundos. El numero de columnas a consultar afecta al tiempo de respuesta de la query?